# Is there any software that could analyze USB logic level log data in a csv file?

Tags: usb, logging

I have a ".csv" log file that stores the USB logic levels (D+/D- logic levels) of a USB device. The format of the file is listed below :

```
1.616545667,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1.616545750,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1.616545833,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
.....
```

The 1st column is "time", the 2nd column is logic level of "D+", the 3rd column is the logic level of "D-", the other columns are not used.

I want to know that is there any software (best to be free) that could analyze the ".csv" file and report the "USB requests" that are involved.

In fact, I am debugging a self-made USB device. I could use an USB oscilloscope to log the USB D+/D- levels of the device into a ".csv" file and I want a software that could report to me what was happenning or what was wrong from the ".csv" file.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want see exactly logical levels on USB, it would be better to use some logical analyzer (it should be better than oscilloscope too). But it is not possible to get logical levels directly to computer, because there is an periphery in chipset, that stores data from USB directly to FIFO queues and no higher layer does know something about this.

But in lot of cases you want to know only packets going throw USB port. If you use linux, you can use Wireshark http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB . On the Windows you will need virtual box with linux or you may try to use http://www.wingmanteam.com/usbsnoopy/